# show that derivative greater than or equal to $1$ leads to a contradiction

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[a, b] \to [a, b]$ be a continuous function which is
differentiable on $(a, b)$ and $f(a) = a$ , $f(b) = b$ , also there is a point $c\in(a, b)$ such that $f′(c)\ne 1$ prove that the statement " $f′(x)\ge 1$ for all $x\in (a, b)$ " leads to a contradiction.

intuitively it seems that if $f′(x)\ge 1$ for all $x\in (a, b)$ and $f(a) = a$  then $f(b) \ne b$  but I can't show this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x.$ Assume $f(a)=a, f(b)=b$ (that is, $g(a)=g(b)=0.)$ We have that $g(x)\ge 0$ (which follows from $g'(x)=f'(x)-1\ge 0$.) Now, by assumption, there exists $c$ such that $g'(c)>0.$ So $g$ cannot be identically zero. Again, $g'(x)\ge 0$ impliest that $g$ is increasing. This contradicts that $g(b)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

If $f'(x)\ge 1$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, and $f'(c)>1$ at some point $c\in(a,b)$ then
$$b-a=\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx> \int_a^b 1\,dx=b-a$$

That mean if you go for 1 hour with a speed always greater or equal 1 km/h, then you cover the distance at least 1 km. If you once exceed the speed, then you cover strictly more.